# Can i add wordpress editor to my custom theme option?

Tags: themes, options

I want to add wordpress default editor to my custom theme option editor, recently i have used textarea but this doesn't support for html format  !

```
// Start Booking Section 
            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'name' => 'booking',
                'label' => __('Booking Code !', 'machan'),
                'description' => __('Add Booking Code for front-end display !', 'machan'),
                'default' => '',
            ),
            // End Booking Section
```

I am using vafpress framework 2.0 for wordpress back-end theme option and metaboxes.

Comment: are you use any framework?

Comment: yes i am using vafpress framework !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if you use vafpress framework as you say 
so you only have small change :)
just use wpeditor instate of textarea :)

```
    array(
        'type' => 'codeeditor',
        'name' => 'booking',
        'label' => __('Booking Code !', 'machan'),
        'description' => __('Add Booking Code for front-end display !', 'machan'),
        'mode' => 'html',
    ),
```

Comment: i used wpeditor but it doesn't support !

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3GtLdqF.png this one is what wordpress default page displaying and http://i.imgur.com/5LEfbcQ.png this is displaying on booking option after added wpeditor.

Comment: I mean there's no option of html/text which default wordpress has

Comment: if you mean don't support `html`, that because `vafpress` support html in Code Editor only build on `Ace Editor`

Comment: So that in front-end it is displaying like this http://i.imgur.com/fijV7R1.png

Comment: Can i add Ace Editor in vafpress ? Does it support ? or any way to do ? Please suggest me !

Comment: yeah just change `type=>'codeeditor'` and `mode=>'html'`

Comment: i edited my answer for you

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9hHtnGl.png